# fetch the radiobutton value on form submit

Tags: angular, radio-button, submit

how to pass radio button value on form submit

```
    <form 
       (submit)="transactionreport(formd.Eng,formd.kan,formd.chckreport>
      <div class="sidemenu">
                <div class="billmenu">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio"   
     name="chckreport" formControlName="basicrpt" 
    [(ngModel)]="formd.chckreport"   
                            [value]="basicrpt" (change)="basic()" checked>
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios5">
                            Basic Report
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" 
     name="chckreport" formControlName="detailrpt" 
    [(ngModel)]="formd.chckreport"
                            value="detailrpt" (change)="detail()" >
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios6">
                            Detail Report
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="chckreport"  [(ngModel)]="formd.chckreport" 
                            value="statementrpt" (change)="statement()" >
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
                            Statement
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" 
    name="chckreport"  [(ngModel)]="formd.chckreport"
                            value="dailycollrpt" (change)="dailycoll()" >
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios4">
                            Daily Collection Report
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>


    transactionreport(Eng:boolean,kan:boolean,chckrepot:string)
    {
      console.log(chckrepot);
    }
```

the `chckrepot` value is undefined but i need the value of the radio button the is selected

Comment: are you trying to use template-driven or reactive form and also the syntax for calling transactionreport is incorrect

Comment: yes but how can i pass radio button group value on form submit? please help me!

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to get the selected radio value:

```
<form (submit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
  <input type="radio" ngModel name="sampleRadio" value="radio1">
  <input type="radio" ngModel name="sampleRadio" value="radio2">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

and in ts:

```
onSubmit(form) {
  console.log(form.value)
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sekotw)

Answer (score -1):

If its a reactive form you should not use ngModel.

HTML PAGE

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)=submit(form)>
   <label>
     <input type="radio" value="Male" formControlName="gender">
       <span>male</span>
   </label>
   <label>
     <input type="radio" value="Female" formControlName="gender">
       <span>female</span>
   </label>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

TS PAGE

```
  form: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      gender: new FormControl("")
    });
  }

  submit(f) {
    console.log(f.value);
  }
```

Please check the sample code here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sclcob

Comment: @VishwasC - I have edited the answer. Please check it.

Mark it as answer if it solves your problem. Happy Coding :)

Comment: but can we do the same procedure using ngmodel instead of formControlName

Comment: Yes we can. With recent versions of angular it is recommended to use reactive forms. However we can use ngModel. Please mark it as answer and help other community members. If you need help with ngModel the answer by "Ramesh" uses ngModel